# Vagrant won't start unless Virtualbox log window is open

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I always get timeout error when running `vagrant up` command. I tried increasing the timeout in the Vagrantfile but it doesn't work. But if I try to open Virtualbox GUI and open the log window (right clicking on the box then click "Show Log") it starts without any problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: Same problem after one of the Vagrant updates. Used to work for years without such problem